# What is difference between sadness and sorrow?

Tags: meaning, differences, word-usage

What is the difference between sadness and sorrow? I researched a lot on internet but the results literally show the same meaning.

If both sadness and sorrow are different, what are their usage?

Comment: Can you share the results of your research on the Internet?

Comment: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100415045836AAFBqQo

Comment: *sorrow:* "1. deep distress, sadness, or regret especially for the loss of someone or something loved; 2. a cause of grief or sadness 3. a display of grief or sadness" MW http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sorrow *Sadness is one of the "six basic emotions" described by Paul Ekman, along with happiness, anger, surprise, fear and disgust.* WP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadness *Sorrow 'is more "intense" than sadness...it implies a long term state'* WP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorrow_%28emotion%29 HTH

Comment: Can you use both words with examples?

Comment: Do you notice the use of *sadness* in the definition of sorrow? Does that give an idea?

Comment: Sadness is what sadness is, and sorrow is the feeling of sadness. But sadness is itself a feeling. This is what I understood. :P

Comment: These terms a more or less equivalent which to use depends on how you feel. Sadness, Sorrow [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sadness%2Csorrow&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csadness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csorrow%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadness is defined in the Oxford dictionary as follows:

> **sadness** /ˈsadnəs  /
>
> ▸noun [mass noun] the condition or quality of being sad:
>
> *a source of great sadness.*
>
> [count noun] *it is one of life's sadnesses.*

It defines sad as:

> **sad** /sad  /
>
> adjective 
>   (sadder, saddest)
>
> feeling or showing sorrow; unhappy:
>
> *I was sad and subdued | theylooked at her with sad, anxious faces.*
>
> ▪ causing or characterized by sorrow or regret; unfortunate and regrettable:
>
> *he told her the sad story of his life | a sad day for us all.*

Therefore sadness can be said to be a state or condition of unhappiness.

Sorrow is defined as:

> **sorrow** /ˈsɒrəʊ  /
>
> noun [mass noun] a feeling of deep distress caused by loss
>
> disappointment, or other misfortune suffered by oneself or others:
>
> *a bereaved person needs time to work through their sorrow.*
>
> ▪ [count noun] an event or circumstance that causes sorrow:
>
> *it was a great sorrow to her when they separated.*
>
> ▪ the outward expression of grief; lamentation.
>
> verb [no obj.] feel or display deep distress:
>
> (as adj. sorrowing) *the sorrowing widower found it hard to relate to* *his sons.*

Therefore in summary **sadness** is a *state of unhappiness* while **sorrow** is a *sense of deep distress,  disappointment,  or sadness*.

Therefore it can be concluded that sorrow is a more intense form of sadness,  which is the basic feeling of unhappiness.

Answer (score 5):

As @Kris searched: Sorrow 'is more "intense" than sadness...it implies a long term state'. Example:

I felt [sadness](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/sadness?s=t) after my father died but I live with [sorrow](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/sorrow?s=t) since my only son was killed in the war.

Comment: Short and to the point.

Answer (score 2):

James Fernald, *Funk & Wagnalls Standard Handbook of Synonyms,  Antonyms & Prepositions* (1947) lists *sadness* and *sorrow* (along with nine other words) as synonyms under the general heading "Grief." Here is how Fernald distinguishes between the two terms:

> *Grief* is acute mental pain resulting from loss, misfortune, or deep disappointment. *Grief* is more acute and less enduring than *sorrow*; *sorrow* and *grief* are for definite cause; *sadness* and *melancholy* may arise from a vague sense of want or loss, from a low state of health, or other ill-defined cause; sadness may be momentary; *melancholy* is more enduring, and may become chronic.

But *sorrow* also appears under other general headings, including "Misfortune," "Mourn," and "Repentance," whereas sadness does not.

S.I. Hayakawa, *Choose the Right Word: A Modern Guide to Synonyms* (1968) has this comment about *sorrow* as a verb:

> **Sorrow** may suggest milder feelings or a less tragic loss than the foregoing words [*grieve*, *mourn*, and *lament*]; it combines sadness with regret, contrasting with *lament* by suggesting *grieving* that is inward or, at most, quietly express: [example omitted].

Hayakawa does not address *sadness* or *sorrow* as a noun at all.

*Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1984) makes *sadness* and *sorrow* the lead words in two separate groups of synonyms—neither of which includes the other. The entry for *sadness* includes coverage of the related terms *depression*, *melancholy*, *melancholia*, *dejection*, *gloom*, *blues*, and *dumps*. The entry for *sorrow* includes coverage of *grief*, *heartache*, *heartbreak*, *anguish*, *woe*, and *regret*. The MW entry for the *sadness* group offers these remarks:

> [The terms related to *sadness*] are comparable when they mean a state of mind when one is unhappy or low-spirited or an attack of low spirits. **Sadness** is the general term; apart from the context it carries no explicit suggestions of the cause of the low spirits or of the extent to which one is deprived of cheerfulness [examples omitted]

As for the *sorrow* group, MW has this:

> [The terms related to *sorrow*], though not close synonyms, share the idea of distress of mind. **Sorrow** is the most general term, implying a sense of loss or of guilt [examples omitted]

The Merriam-Webster treatment of the two words suggests that the source of confusion between them isn't so much the similarity of the feelings they describe as the level of generality that each word operates on. *Sadness* is a very general term for feelings of unhappiness or dispiritedness, while *sorrow* is a very general term for feelings of loss or guilt. Hayakawa seems to see an overlap between *sorrow* and *sadness*, but views *sorrow* as distinguishable by its admixture of regret, which *sadness* does not centrally possess. Fernald argues that *sorrow* (being more intensely felt) is traceable to a definite cause, while sadness (being more diffuse) may not be.

Answer (score 1):

Sorrow is sadness with a more defined reason, i.e. loss, disappointment, bad action of others.

Sadness is a more general sentiment with a less precise definition.